# Плагин проверки форм (сообщение об ошибке)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

С помощью плагина validate когда форма заполнена не правильно (ввести в поле слова а не цифры, и нажать на кнопку отправить) появляется сообщение об ошибке - путём появления элемента label с классом "error". Так вот, нужно чтобы данный элемент появлялся плавно с методом slideDown. Как такое устроить?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  
$('form').validate();

$('label.error').slideDown();
      
});
```

```css
div{
border:1px black solid;
}
label.error{
display:none;
background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<form>
<div>
<input type="text" class="number" name="nam" title="Ошибка!">
</div>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Отправить">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В validate должен быть функционал для вызова функций в случай ошибки и он есть.
В достаточно написать свою функцию, которая будет вызывать slideDown() у блока с ошибкой.

```
$("#myform").validate({
  invalidHandler: function(event, validator) {
    // 'this' указывает на проверяемую форму.
    var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids(); // функция которая возвращает количество неверно заполненных форм
    if (errors) { // проверяет наличие, если больше 0
      var message = errors == 1 // тернарный оператор
        ? 'You missed 1 field. It has been highlighted' // если ошибка 1, то возвращает это
        : 'You missed ' + errors + ' fields. They have been highlighted'; // если больше, то возвращает текст с количеством ошибок
      $("div.error span").html(message); // ищем span в div.error и меняем в нем содержимое 
      $("div.error").show(); // показываем блок div.error
    } else {
      $("div.error").hide(); // скрываем блок, если ошибок нет.
    }
  }
});
```

https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#invalidhandler

Так же если интересно, то можно использовать css решения slidedown.

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');
const error = document.querySelector('.error');
input.oninput = function(e) {
 if (e.target.value) {
   error.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
   error.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```css
.errors {
  overflow:hidden;
}

.error {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  animation-name: slideInDown;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration: 1;
}

@keyframes slideInDown {
  from {
    transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
    visibility: visible;
  }

  to {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
<div class="errors">
  <div class="error" style="display: none;">
    Ошибка
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, можете первый вариант где "функционал для вызова функций в случай ошибки" построчно разъяснить?

Comment: Дополнил ответ, дописал комментарии на каждую строчку кода